# Angular bootstrap UI typeahead error

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I recently updated the Angular UI bootstrap. When page load I am getting this error-

> Error: [$compile:tplrt] Template for directive 'uibTypeaheadPopup'
>   must have exactly one root element.
>   uib/template/typeahead/typeahead-popup.html

My template file which has the input tag has proper root element.

```
<div>
<div class="form-row">
    <div class="form-cell"><label class="control-label">Cc : </label></div>
    <div class="form-cell">
        <input name="ccClientInput" type="text" ng-model="asyncSelected"
               uib-typeahead="address as address.SearchDisplay for address in clientCcSearch.getClients($viewValue)"
               typeahead-loading="loadingLocations"
               typeahead-editable="false"
               typeahead-wait-ms="300"
               placeholder="Search for colleagues"
               class="clientcc-search">
        <div>
            <span ng-repeat="client in CcClients">
                <span class="clientcc">
                    <span class="client-tooltip" tooltip tooltip-contents="createTooltip(client)">{{client.Name}}</span>
                    <span ng-click="removeClientCC($index)" class="cursor-pointer ccCl">
                        <i class="icon-remove-on-s"></i>
                    </span>
                </span>
            </span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue was spelling mistake in the tpls while adding it to grunt.
Thanks,
RZ

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that, You have not closed one of the `<div>` element.

Comment: If you look closely i dont see any div tags open.

Comment: the first <div> is not closed.